# How do I get my elevatedButton widget to call the function in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, function, widget

I'm trying to get my elevated button to respond to a function that I created in another widget but am having problems with it incrementing. Could someone please assist and tell me what I am doing wrong? I have everything situated in the answer.dart file for it to call the answerQuestion function

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './questions.dart';
import './answer.dart';


// Main that runs the MyApp class
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

// Stateful MyApp
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

// MyAppState  Generic State
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _questionIndex = 0;
  // ignore: unused_local_variable
  void _answerQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
    });
    print(_questionIndex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // FIRST METHOD

    // QUESTION VARIABLE
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    var questions = [
      'What\'s your favorite food?',
      'What\'s your favorite color?'
    ];

    // RETURNS MATERIAL APP FOR FLUTTER
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My First App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
           Question(
            questions[_questionIndex],
          ),
          Answer(_answerQuestion),
          Answer(_answerQuestion),
          Answer(_answerQuestion),
         ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

answer.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 
class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function selectHandler;
 
 Answer({Key? key, required this.selectHandler}) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 9, 131, 232),
          ),
          child: Text('Answer'),
          
          onPressed: () {
            selectHandler;
          },
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

questions.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 
class Question extends StatelessWidget {
  final String questionText;
 
  Question(this.questionText);
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Text(
        questionText,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include related part like `Question` and `Answer`.

Comment: It is likely that you are not invoking the method inside the answer widget. It would be great if you provided the Answer class

Comment: It seems you're missing a ( and a ) (or simply remove the anonymous function wrapping it)

Answer (score 0):

same as previous answer
make these changes.

```
onPressed: selectHandler,
```

and

```
Answer(selectHandler: _answerQuestion),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change:

`final function selectHandler;`

to

`final VoidCallback selectHandler;`

Answer (score -1):

You can do

```dart
 onPressed: () {
   selectHandler(); //missing ()
```

Or do

```dart
 onPressed: selectHandler,
```

Another thing on Answer widget, you are using a named argument , do like

```dart
 Answer(selectHandler: _answerQuestion),
```

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I don't have & dont worry about it.

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour) and [flutter-cookbook](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook)

Comment: one last question. I wont to change my text color for my elevated button. I used the object textColor: Colors.black but i keep getting error and it saids textColor isn't defined.

Comment: You can follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66756474/10157127) or [ElevatedButton doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html). Also check [breaking-changes/buttons](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons)

Comment: thank you I just looked at the documentation and saw onPrimary. Again thank you for all your help. have a blessed day ধন্যবাদ বন্ধু